Google OAuth 2.0 issues
I'm having issues with authenticating with Google. I am using react front-end with node as back-end, with an Express server.
Here is the Google API Client side information:

My server endpoint (server running on port 3000) (using the oauth2client from here https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client?tab=readme-ov-file#generating-an-authentication-url)

Front-end function:

Function in use in .jsx file:

And here is the error in the console:

And finally, here is the error found in Google's OAuth side of things:

